# Quickest way to iterate on custom OpenWRT builds

Tags: linux, networking, openwrt

I've been playing with the OpenWRT Attitude Adjustment trunk on my TL-MR3020 lately, and since I'm modifying some of the included packages that get installed via feeds, I need to reflash the firmware a *lot*.  And the problem here is that it's very time consuming.  I'd like to optimize this process as much as possible, and the first optimization I can come up with is precluding any need for network reconfiguration after reflashing.

Currently, after I use `mtd` to reflash my firmware, I have to log in via the serial console and modify `/etc/config/network` to put the router on the right subnet, and to specify the gateway and dns.  It sure would make a lot of sense if I could have this happen automatically every time.

I'm very new to Linux, so my first thought was to have a shell script run that edits `/etc/config/wireless/` and then does a `/etc/init.d/network restart` to bring up the network interface(s).  Then I thought that there must be a command-line equivalent to setting the gateway and dns, and then I could follow those commands up with `/etc/init.d/network restart`.

How would you all approach this problem?  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer that just dawned on me is that I could modify `/etc/sysupgrade.conf' and enter in all of the files and directories that I want to preserve, and then use the`sysupgrade` command to flash the sysupgrade-specific build.

That said, I would still like to have a way to flash a router from scratch and have the proper `/etc/config/network` settings, so my original question technically stands.